# Is it possible to set custom shortcuts show up in the cheat sheet shown by holding <super> in unity?

Tags: unity

Is it possible to set custom shortcuts show up in the cheat sheet shown by holding <kbd>super</kbd> in unity?

Basically asking where these shortcuts are fetched from, and if possible can they be altered without actually changing said bindings.

[image]

I'm interested if the feature could be used to display for example git or terminal commands cheat sheets.

Comment: Great idea! Actually we could go further but the thing is that the initiatee of an idea should be the one who codes it

Comment: Such greatness, much vision, very funky :P

Comment: I filed a feature suggestion on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1591109). you can add yourself to it to make it heard.

Answer (score 3):

If you edit key-bindings using `CCSM -> General Options`, the updated settings will show up straight away in the Cheat Sheet.

If you want to add new key-bindings you can do this in `CCSM` with the `Commands` plug-in, these won't show up in the Cheat Sheet.

It seems that the Cheat Sheet only reports specific key-bindings from the list, you could change that list if you want to go into the source and rebuild it, then integrate it back into your system. You could suggest it as a feature on the unity page in [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/unity)

Comment: I filed a feature suggestion on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1591109). you can add yourself to it to make it heard.

Answer (score 0):

Go into System Settings.

Open Keyboard and select the Shortcuts tab.

Select Custom Shortcuts in the left pane, and click the <kbd>+</kbd> button (or click the <kbd>+</kbd> button in any category). The Custom Shortcut window will appear.

Type a Name to identify the shortcut, and a command to run an application, then click <kbd>Apply</kbd>. For example, if you wanted the shortcut to open Rhythmbox, you could name it Music and use the rhythmbox command.

Click Disabled in the row that was just added. When it changes to New accelerator…, hold down the desired shortcut key combination.

You would need to figure out the command for opening the dash, etc.